# Issues with Ubuntu Unity

Tags: unity, gnome, nvidia, dell, intel

When I boot into Ubuntu on my Dell Dimension 9100 with Nvidia 7300 le graphics, everything works fine until I login, then unity freezes after a few seconds.  I need some way to boot into Ubuntu in terminal only mode without already being logged on, then some commands that will either replace unity with gnome or make unity more compatible with older graphics.

Comment: try adding a new user and logging in to the new acccount to check whether the problem lies with the user of the account `sudo adduser newuser` _you can replace newuser with anything you like. *nospaces*_ You will fill out a bunch of info. Just make sure you get the password right. Try this and report back

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help:

1. `Ctrl+F1` then login with your user
2. `$ export DISPLAY=:0`
3. `$ sudo service lightdm restart`
4. back to desktop: `Ctrl+F7`